# Reasons why fgetc() and/or fputc() is inconsistent

Tags: c, file-io, stream

Given the following snippet, `fin` containing random text with `data` always following a `command`:

```
#define COMMANDSIZE 16
#define DATASIZE 128

int i, j, k, ch;

char command[COMMANDSIZE];
char data[DATASIZE];

FILE* fin;
FILE* fout;

fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");

fseek(fout, 0, SEEK_SET);

while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)
{
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(command); i++) //obtain command from input stream
    {
         command[i] = fgetc(fin) & 0xff;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(data); j++) //obtain data from input stream
    {
         data[j] = fgetc(fin) & 0xff;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < sizeof(data); k++) //write data to output stream
    {
         fseek(fout, /* computed block address */, SEEK_CUR);
         fputc(data[k], fout);
    }
}

fclose(fout);
fclose(fin);
```

Comparing the input and output file, some data in the input file did not carry over. Thus, I tried doing the above with `while(1)`, and again, some data in the input file did not carry over, but it wasn't the same data as using `while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)`, and there was not an intersect (some overlap) between the different output files.

**How can I ensure all data from the input file is written to the output file?** Does this have to do with `fgetc()` and/or `fputc()`?

Comment: And why aren't you just using `fread` and `fwrite`?

Comment: you seem to have misunderstood file I/O, fseek is not needed in your case and especially not if you open the file in text mode.

Comment: `fseek` in my application will write to a specific block address. How would I write to a specific block address otherwise?

Comment: I inherited the code with `fgetc()` and `fputc()`.

Comment: well if you have the files in text mode then that will not work since when you read in text mode it does funny things with the newline character.

Comment: @claptrap I see. `fgetc()` and `fputc()` would read in text mode?

Comment: your fopen() uses "r" and "w" resp. which is textmode by default, for binary mode use "rb" and "wb"

Comment: Show us a small sample of the data input, the output you get, and the output you want.  You should be checking each of the `fgetc()` calls for errors.  The masking operation in the assignments is not necessary.

Comment: Are you sure there's no overlap between any of the block addresses? That would explain why some of the input isn't being carried over to the output file -- some are overwriting others.

Comment: @Barmar That makes sense. Thus, through logging, I could see each command and data that had been read and found that some commands and data weren't even being read. When I used `while(1)`, a different set of commands and data were being read. Thus, that led to my theory that `fgetc()` (and/or `fputc()`) may be causing issues.

Comment: Why are you using logging?  Stepping through the code in a debugger should show you what's going wrong very quickly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Added the sample. This is the output I want (left) and the output I get (right). This is consistent throughout the file.

Comment: It is illegal to use absolute `fseek` with files open in text mode. Text mode streams can only be positioned to `0` position or to a position previously returned by `ftell`. You are not allowed to "`fseek` to a specific block" in a text stream.

Comment: @CareyGregory Functionality of my code. Also, it's hard to have debuggers installed into the environment I am using. I don't think gdb is installed.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to answer this question with the information given.  At a minimum we would need to see the actual parameters to `fseek` and not just a comment stating _random block address._  Also, as @AndreyT points out, using absolute offsets with `fseek` in text mode will _not_ work.

Comment: @AndreyT Can this be done in a binary stream? How can I seek to a specific block? Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you for trying to show the data; sadly, what you show is almost unreadable (ancient eyes over here) and does not self-evidently bear any relation to what your code does. At least, the 'MFD Row _NN_' part is not generated by your program. Can you generate a straight forward hex dump of the first couple of entries of the data file, and then a hex dump of the corresponding output?  And display that as normal 'code' in your question. The 'seek to random block address' part of the question doesn't inspire confidence. If it is truly random, then how can you tell whether the output is correct?

Comment: Yes, of course you can seek to a specific block.  It's done just the way you're doing it, but since we don't know how you're computing the seek address, we have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: @edmastermind29: Yes, if you want to seek to specific numerical positions in the stream, you have to open it as a binary stream. This might not be the issue in your case though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The code above is a sample of what I am doing...you wanted the output I want vs. the output I am getting, so I tried to provide that. The block address is not random in my actual code. The logging I have done shows what commands and data are being read. The issue is not **all** the commands and data are being read. Using `while ((ch = fgetc(fi) != EOF)` reads different commands and data than `while(1)` given the same input file. Hence, my questioning regarding `fgetc()`.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am logging and can determine that the seek address is correct (comparing the addresses to log and output.txt and the associated data). Thus, I am marking as "random" as that is not my issue in this application. See comment above.

Comment: Then please don't claim "random" when you don't mean "random".  Say "computed" or something.  The functions `fgetc()` and `fputc()` are as near 100% reliable as anything in computing is.  The problem is in your code.  Our problem is that we can't yet see exactly what your code is.  We need an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) and the exact data you're using so that we can attempt to reproduce your problem, and try to understand what's going wrong.  We can make guesses, but that's all they are, because we don't know what you expect or really have.

Comment: @AndreyT: you're correct that the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.9.2 **The `fseek` function**) states: _For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by
an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file
and whence shall be SEEK_SET._  In practice, that's the lowest common denominator rules. Unix-based systems are more flexible and permit the same operations on text files as they do on binary.  Granted, the platform has not been stated yet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The block address is "computed" (see above). I have determined that the block addressing and what is being written to that address is correct (I can compare my log to what I have in output.txt). Hence, I am trying to display what my issue is, which is the discrepancy of having **all** the data being written (not just portions), and changing the `while` loop is serving different results. I appreciate the help and thanks for SSCCE, but I am not comfortable with providing my actual code with what I am working on. If I'm not able to be helped because of that, then okay. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `fgetc`.  You say the way you've shown above produces different input than some other method you haven't shown.  If that is so, then the other method is broken, or there's even more code you've omitted that is broken.

Comment: @CareyGregory `fgetc()` is fine. Done. Why do I get different results when I change my `while` loop? That's what causes different results, and I have shown that above. I have shown one method to another, which are the changes in the `while` loop. The rest of the code does not change otherwise...and if my other methods are broken, then okay, I can work on those.

Comment: Change your `while` loop in what way?  We can't speculate on code we haven't seen.

Comment: From `while((ch = fget(fin)) != EOF)` to `while(1)`.

Comment: `while (1)` does no input.  You're not showing us all the code.

Comment: "`while(1)` does no input." What is the significance of that vs. my other `while` loop? I have the same code inside the loop regardless. `while(1)` runs infinitely whereas `while((ch = fget(fin)) =! EOF)` runs until `fin` reaches `EOF`, but why would that change any data if the code inside the loop stays the same? If you cannot help me with the code I have given, then thanks for your help. I have enough suggestions to try and go from here.

Answer (score 2):

A few things are not clear to me here.

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)
```

Do you intend to throw away the character you just read?

```
fseek(fout, 1, SEEK_CUR);
```

Why are you skipping ahead one byte?  Writing will advance the file automatically.  I don't think you want to advance the file position twice.

Comment: The above is a snippet. In my application, I am using `fseek` to go to a specific block address.

Comment: You're doing it each time through the `for (k` loop. What does that have to do with going to a specific block address?

Comment: Again, the above is an example snippet of what I am doing.

Comment: @edmastermind29 For every single byte? Do you store each byte at a different block?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes. Depending on the command.

Comment: @edmastermind29 If that example is not your real code, maybe yuo should post the real code se we can help you wtih that...

Comment: @RedX Then, I am displaying irrelevant code. Using `while(1)` and `while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF)` yields different output.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this instead:

```
char command[COMMANDSIZE];
char data[DATASIZE];

FILE* fin;
FILE* fout;

fin = fopen("input.txt", "rb");
fout = fopen("output.txt", "wb");

while (fread(command, sizeof(command), 1, fin) != EOF)
{
    if (fread(data, sizeof(data), 1, fin) != EOF)
    {
        fseek(...);  /* Seek to the block where current data should be written */
        fwrite(data, sizeof(data), 1, fout);
    }
}
```